# Updating data from an activity to a widget isn't working

Tags: android, android-activity

Well I am in this situation, I have an activity and a widget connected to it, I put all the necessary code for confirming, sending and updating data from my activity to the widget, or so I thought because data aren't updating at all. I miss something but I don't know what.

All my code is working except for the updating part.When pressing the confirm `button` in activity nothing happens to the widget.

**Here is my activity code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

NumberPicker dayPicker, monthPicker, yearPicker;
Button confirmButton;
int day,month,year;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    dayPicker = findViewById(R.id.dayPicker);
    monthPicker = findViewById(R.id.monthPicker);
    yearPicker = findViewById(R.id.yearPicker);
    dayPicker.setMinValue(1);
    dayPicker.setMaxValue(31);
    monthPicker.setMinValue(1);
    monthPicker.setMaxValue(12);
    yearPicker.setMinValue(1950);
    yearPicker.setMaxValue(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
    confirmButton = findViewById(R.id.confirmationButton);
    confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            day = dayPicker.getValue();
            month = monthPicker.getValue();
            year = yearPicker.getValue();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
BirthdayWidget.class);
            intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
            intent.putExtra("day",day);
            intent.putExtra("month",month);
            intent.putExtra("year",year);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

**And here is my widget code:**

```
 public class BirthdayWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

int day,month,year;

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        java.util.Calendar calendar = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
        Date d1 = calendar.getTime();
        Date d2 = new Date( Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) - year + 90,
                month-1,day);
        long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
        long dayLong = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        String dayString = Long.toString(dayLong);
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.birthday_widget);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text,dayString+" days until birthday!");

        int id = appWidgetIds[0];
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(id, remoteViews);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    day = intent.getIntExtra("day",1);
    month = intent.getIntExtra("month",1);
    year = intent.getIntExtra("year",2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you put the receiver tag in manifest?. Like this.

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.MyReceiver" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="your_package.USER_ACTION />
</intent-filter>
```

Put this under application tag

Comment: Yes here it is: <receiver android:name=".BirthdayWidget">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/birthday_widget_info" />
        </receiver>

Comment: Change this "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" to "android.appwidget.ACTION_.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"

Comment: Is it possible that something missing in onReceive or even replace onReceive with something else in order to work properly?